# I want to push my messages in an Array and show on HTML <p>

Tags: html, ionic-framework

For learning purpose I'm creating a Chat App. I am trying to display the message in the same page on which I'm sending the message, for that I need to push my messages into an Array and display the same in

```
<p>Response :</p>
<p>{{responseTxt}}</p>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Your chat</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <p>Response :</p>
    <p>{{responseTxt}}</p>

    <ion-footer>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Type your message here..</ion-title>
            <input class="txt" type="text" placeholder="Type your message.."
                [(ngModel)]="userChats"
            />
            <ion-icon name="send" (click)=pushChat(userChats)></ion-icon>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
</ion-content>
```

And here is my controller: TS file:

```
export class ChatPage {
    responseTxt: any;


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage');
    }


    pushChat(u){
        if(this.responseTxt== "" || this.responseTxt== null){
            this.responseTxt = u;
        }else{
            this.responseTxt = this.responseTxt+" " +u;
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me with my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your code looks like it should already work.  Can you please describe what is not working as expected?

Comment: This is my code which is working, but I want to push the chat data to an array and then display within this variable: "responseTxt"
Also if possible I want to push data to print in new line every time when I click pushChat(). Same like whatsapp messenger. I am new on ionic so dont exactly know how to do this

Comment: I've posted an answer based on my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `responseTxt` to an array data type, and initialise it:

```
responseTxt: string[] = [];
```

Rewrite your `pushChat` method to add an array element to the array with each new message:

```
pushChat(u) {
    this.responseTxt.push(u);
}
```

Use `ngFor` in your template to iterate over the content of the array:

```
<p>Response :</p>
<ul *ngFor="let message of responseTxt">
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Apologies, as I was away for a while so I did not get time to test the code. Now I tried and it worked on one go. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I ask another question here or I need to open a new question for that?

I have created an App for chatting. 
I have designed it the way where it can fetch all the old chats when you select a particular contact to chat with. Here is the code that I wrote in ionViewDidLoad():

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage');

    this.chat.getChatTable(this.loggedInUser, this.toMessageUser).then(data => {
   console.log("I have received : " + JSON.stringify(data));
   this.responseTxt = data;
  })
    
  }

Comment: Can you suggest a service or trick of Ionic itself so that I can write a function which will run continuously as long as this page is open? So that I can fetch the messages which is being sent by my contact to me?  I have heard something like Service Worker...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback—please consider marking this answer as accepted so the question stops showing up in the Unanswered list.  I'd create a new question for your next problem, because it looks like it might require a bit more discussion on how the backend fetches the messages, whether it can be rewritten to use Observables, etc.

Comment: I have marked the answer as working solution, kindly add me too when you create a new question, hope you understood my question.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't answer you clearly—I recommend that you publish the new question.